# Unable to get * or ** for p-value in the final table for t-test

Tags: r

Unable to get asterisk symbol for p-values in the final table

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Original data
Input_data <- data.frame(
  Tags = c("Genotype 1", "Genotype 2", "Genotype 3", "Genotype 4", "Genotype 5", "Genotype 6", "Genotype 7", "Genotype 8", "Genotype 9"),
  Control_1 = c(50, 45, 48, 52, 47, 49, 51, 43, 46),
  Control_2 = c(52, 47, 50, 55, 49, 51, 53, 42, 48),
  Control_3 = c(48, 43, 46, 50, 45, 47, 49, 41, 44),
  Treatment_1 = c(60, 57, 51, 62, 59, 61, 63, 65, 56),
  Treatment_2 = c(58, 59, 50, 64, 61, 63, 65, 67, 58),
  Treatment_3 = c(62, 55, 56, 60, 57, 59, 61, 63, 54)
)

# Reshape the data into long format
long_data <- Input_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Tags, names_to = "Group", values_to = "Value") %>%
  separate(Group, into = c("Group", "Replicate"), sep = "_")

# Calculate mean and SD for each Tag-Group combination
summary_data <- long_data %>%
  group_by(Tags, Group) %>%
  summarise(
    Mean = mean(Value),
    SD = sd(Value)
  )

# Arrange the data for final output
final_Output <- summary_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = c(Mean, SD)) %>%
  mutate(
    Control = paste0(format(round(Mean_Control, 2), nsmall = 2), " ± ", format(round(SD_Control, 2), nsmall = 2)),
    Treatment = paste0(format(round(Mean_Treatment, 2), nsmall = 2), " ± ", format(round(SD_Treatment, 2), nsmall = 2)),
    Fold_Change = log2(Mean_Treatment / Mean_Control),  # Calculate Fold Change
    P_Value = ifelse(abs(Fold_Change) < 0.05, "*", ifelse(abs(Fold_Change) < 0.01, "**", ""))
  ) %>%
  select(Tags, Control, Treatment, Fold_Change, P_Value) %>% 
  unite("Fold_Change_P_Value", c("Fold_Change", "P_Value"), sep = "")

# Print the final arranged table with Fold Change and P-Value
print(final_Output)
```

I am unable to identify the mistake in my code.

Comment: Your test for the `P_value` looks wrong.  You are using limits of 0.05 and 0.01, but comparing those to the absolute value of the fold change, not to a calculated p-value.

Comment: Can I get more info on the same. Thanks

Comment: That's a stats question, not a programming question.  Maybe ask on CrossValidated?